# Why is onKeyUp or onKeyDown not getting called for certain characters?

Tags: event-handling, android-emulator, android, android-keypad

In my activity, I have an onKeyUp and onKeyDown event handlers, which are called for normal characters and even for some unicode characters like cedilla (ç). But not for others like á, à, ü, é, č, š, ž, è, ...

Why is that? And how can I register those key presses (or better yet, characters)?

I am testing this on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with soft keyboard (samsung and swype keyboards), where accented characters are available with a long key press. It is interesting to note that even cedilla (ç), which is available with the same long press, does get registered with onKeyUp/Down event handler.

I am using onKeyUp/Down on the activity. There is no text box or anything text related on the main view. Just a modified ImageView.

I tested this in an emulator as well (default android image 2.3.3) and behaviour is similar to real device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through testing, I found the answer. Most unicode characters are handled by `onKeyMultiple` event handler. If you get

```
keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_UNKNOWN &&  event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE
```

Then you can obtain the unicode character by calling `event.getCharacters()`. It is actually all [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyMultiple%28int,%20int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29), though a bit hard to find.

Comment: Welcome to Samsung num keyboard hell

Comment: And now getCharacters() is deprecated, how are we supposed to get unicode characters? The funniest part is that it still works. (as of API 29)